# How were trigonometrical functions of $\dfrac{2\pi}{17}$ calculated?

Tags: trigonometry

I know they were calculated by Gauss, but how? Is there a method for calculating them?

Comment: Google gives: http://www.jimloy.com/geometry/17-gon.htm with an explicit construction

Comment: See if the following helps: http://pballew.net/Constructable_17gon.pdf

Comment: See section 2 of [Gauss' Method of Constructing a Regular Heptadecagon](http://www.osaka-ue.ac.jp/zemi/nishiyama/math2010/Gauss.pdf) by Yutaka Nishiyama.

Comment: The link in my 29 February 2012 no longer works. See [this web page](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316692623_A_detailed_and_elementary_solution_to_x17_1). After being spammed for years by ResearchGate, when that earlier link to my manuscript stopped working (a few years ago), I "signed up" in order to keep it available on the internet. Why not ArXiv, you might ask? See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50409/13130). (Downvoted twice, but I wanted a place easy for me to find by google for an explanation that I could refer to as needed.)

Comment: You can look in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109390/proof-of-the-radical-expression-of-cos-dfrac-2-pi17/4726027#4726027), where I have given a computation using Galois-theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly(from what I read), Gauss proved that

We can factor a rational multiple of $x^{17} - 1$ as $(x-1)(P(x)^2 + aP(x) + b)$

Where $P(x)$ is an $8^{th}$ degree polynomial with rational coefficients.

This $P(x)$ could in-turn be represented as a quadratic $Q(x)^2 + cQ(x) + d$, where this $Q(x)$ is an $4^{th}$ degree polynomial.

That $Q(x)$ itself was a quadratic of a quadratic!

The actual method of geometrically constructing the polygon came a few years later.

In more modern terms, basically (again, if I remember the terms correctly), the splitting field of $x^{17}-1$ lies in a tower of quadratic extensions, starting from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: See my answer below for some questions which are longer than comments can be.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/17}$.  Since $3$ is a primitive root mod $17$, i.e. a generator of the multiplicative group of nonzero integers mod $17$, write $R_j = \omega^{3^j}$ for $j = 0, 1, \ldots, 15$.  These and $1$ are the $17$'th roots of unity.
For $2^j \le i < 2^{j+1}$ let $x_i = \sum_{k \equiv i \mod 2^j} R_k$.  Then for $2^j \le i < 2^j + 2^{j-1}$, $x_i + x_{i+2^{j-1}}$ and $x_i x_{i+2^{j-1}}$ can be expressed in terms of the previous $x_k$'s, which allows $x_i$ and $x_{i+2^{j-1}}$ to be obtained by solving a quadratic equation: if $x + y = c$ and $xy = d \ne 0$, then $x$ and $y$ are the roots of $z^2 - c z + d$.
Thus:

$$x_1 = \sum_{j=0}^{15} R_j = -1$$

$x_2 = R_0 + R_2 + \ldots + R_{14}$ and $x_3 = R_1 + R_3 + \ldots R_{15}$ satisfy
$x_2 + x_3 = x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 x_3 = 4 x_1 = -4$.

$x_4 = R_0 + R_4 + R_8 + R_{12}$ and $x_6 = R_2 + R_6 + R_{10} + R_{14}$ satisfy
$x_4 + x_6 = x_2$, $x_4 x_6 = -1$

$x_5 =  R_5 + R_9 + R_{13} + R_1$ and $x_7 = R_7 + R_{11} + R_{15} + R_3$ satisfy
$x_5 + x_7 = x_3$, $x_5 x_7 = -1$

$x_8 = R_0 + R_8$ and $x_{12} = R_4 + R_{12}$ satisfy
$x_8 + x_{12} = x_4$, $x_8 x_{12} = x_5$

$x_{16} = R_0 = \omega$ and $x_{24} = R_8$ satisfy $x_{16} + x_{24} = x_8$, $x_{16} x_{24} = 1$