# Can $\cos(2\pi/17)$ be written as nested square roots only?

Tags: trigonometry, field-theory, prime-numbers, radicals, nested-radicals

From [another math.stackexchange.com question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109390/proof-of-the-radical-expression-of-cos-dfrac-2-pi17) we have

[image]

Can this expression be written as a nested square root only?  ie,

[image]

where all of the a's are integers?

Edit: From the comment, it seems that it may be more interesting to look at

[image]

After doing some more research, I found that

[image]

This was based on [this answer to a related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3714939/14162). So it appears that it would be possible with an infinite nested square root.  How about a finite nested square root?  Would that be possible?

Comment: The obvious quick answer is that **No. This is not possible.** The reason is that if $a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_n$ are all integers, then the nested square root is an algebraic integer. But $\cos(2\pi/17)$ is not an algebraic integer. On the other hand, $$2\cos(2\pi/17)=\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}$$ is an algebraic integer as a sum of twoalgebraic integers (this time complex roots of unity). Therefore a much more interesting question is whether $2\cos(2\pi/17)$ is a nested square root of integer terms. Could you please edit the question to make it more interesting?

Answer (score 2):

For all $A$ and $a_i$ it follows: $$A=\sqrt{1+a_1(A+1)+(A-a_1-1)\sqrt{1+a_2(A+2)+(A-a_2)\sqrt{1+a_3(A+3)+\cdots}}}$$

Let $$A=\cos \bigg(\frac{2\pi}{17}\bigg)$$ and let $$a_i=\frac{1}{A+i}$$ then, if $B_n=A-a_n+n-2$, we have

$$\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{17}\bigg)=\sqrt{2+B_1\sqrt{2+B_2\sqrt{2+B_3\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}$$

Any number cna be expressed as an infinite-nested radical, but given that $\cos(2\pi/17)$ is pretty obscure, I think this formula is the best to apply, since it works with infinite parameters and is not periodic (making it interesting!).

Here is an interesting one for *cubed* root (but periodic). Note that $$\color{red}{\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{17}\bigg)}^3=\frac 14\cos \bigg(\frac{6\pi}{17}\bigg)+\frac 34\color{red}{\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{17}\bigg)}$$

thus

$$\cos \frac{2\pi}{17}=\sqrt[3]{\frac 14\cos \bigg(\frac{6\pi}{17}\bigg) +\frac 34\sqrt[3]{\frac 14\cos \bigg(\frac{6\pi}{17}\bigg) +\frac 34\sqrt[3]{\frac 14\cos \bigg(\frac{6\pi}{17}\bigg) +\cdots}}}$$

Comment: Can all of the Bs be integers?  This is what I was looking for.  (Sorry that I didn't specify it correctly.)

Comment: @NoOneinParticular None of $B_n$ can be an integer since $n>0$ is a whole number. Radical equations and trigonometry go hand-in-hand (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals)) but they most often revolve around "units", roots of numbers that neaten results and yield most elegant ones. e.g. $$\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}5\bigg)=\frac 12\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}$$ because the denominator $5$ makes a good unit for radicals (e.g. $a+b\sqrt 5$ forms work in wonderful ways). $17$ is rather obscure, so less elegant radicals in consequence.

Comment: I have generalised the method to solve your question