# Let $ f:(X, d) \mapsto (Y,d) $ be an mapping such that $ Graph (f) $ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, connectedness

Where $ X $ is connected. Does it imply $ f $ to be continuous?

Comment: Another related question: [Characterizing continuous functions based on the graph of the function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/characterizing-continuous-functions-based-on-the-graph-of-the-function)

Answer (score 3):

No. In [*On a connected dense proper subgroup of $\Bbb R^2$ whose complement is connected*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-097-03/S0002-9939-1986-0840645-0/) Ryuji Maehara gives a relatively simple proof of the title result, which is due to F. Burton Jones. The main theorem is that there is an [additive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function) $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that both the graph of $f$ and its complement are dense, connected subsets of $\Bbb R^2$. Such a function cannot be continuous: it’s [well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) that if such a function is continuous, it has the form $f(x)=cx$ for some constant $c\in\Bbb R$.