# Mapping sending compacts to compacts and connected to connected

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A characterization of functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ which are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220410/a-characterization-of-functions-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rm-which-are-co)

Suppose that $f$:$R^m$→$R^n$ sends all compact sets to compact sets,and all connected sets to connected sets.Prove that $f$ is continuous. Obviously continuous functions sends compact sets to compact,and connected to connected,but it is hard for me to prove this special opposite direction. I suppose it is really important to use that $A$ is compact in $R^n$ iff $A$ is closed and bounded but I don't know how to use it.Also,values dimensions $m$ and $n$ are arbitrary,and I guess only important thing about them is that characterisation of compact sets.

Comment: an answer to your question is here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220410/a-characterization-of-real-valued-functions-on-bbb-r-which-are-contiunuous

Comment: I edited that question to generalize it to reflect the existing generalized answers, so this question can now be closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.