# A map of two Euclidean spaces preserving connectedness and compactness is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $ f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. If $f$ preserves connectedness and compactness then $f$ is continuous. How can this be proven? I don't really know where to start.

Comment: You have to prove that the image sets of connected and compact subsets of $R^n$ are connected and compact sets in $R^m$ respectively.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 I think he needs to assume those things and show $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @GregoryGrant what you said.

Comment: The answer is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220410/a-characterization-of-functions-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rm-which-are-co