# Is the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that maps every compact set to compact set and connected set to connected set continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Is the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that maps every compact set to compact set and connected set to connected set continious?

I know that if the function maps only compact set (respectively connected) to compact (connected) it's not continious. I saw the counterexample. Is it also true when we take both properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R,$ or functions from a general topological space to a general topological space, or what?

Comment: Ok. Jimmy R. gave counterexample for general topological spaces. So how is it with function $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220410/a-characterization-of-functions-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rm-which-are-co).

Comment: Ok. I suck in finding stuff. Thanks. That is the awnser for my question.